# False statement by a dominant person in a group survives even if that person leaves the group

Tags: social-psychology, decision-making

Can someone point me to a source for this study:

> There was a group, in which a dominant person established a belief in
>   a false statement by speaking with high confidence. The group still
>   believed in the false statement even after that person had left the
>   group. Newcomers to the group accepted the false statement through
>   normative social influence.

I have read about that either by Kaneman, Ariely, Chabris/Simons or maybe Thaler but can't find the passage anymore. And is this still valid?

I'm not talking about the story with the apes, the banana and the ladder by the way - I know that never happened.

Comment: I'd still be interested in this, by the way. I could not find it under Asch conformity experiments by browsing over the information, I know there are a lot of other conformity experiments. I don't even know where to start searching...